# Possible to get errors from WebBrowser control?

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

Using the standard WebBrowser control is it possible to obtain any errors encountered while rendering the document??  ie.  invalid markup or tags that haven't been closed properly etc.

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you _really need to read_. Among other things, have you tried reading the documentation?

Comment: See [WebBrowser Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx)

Comment: @JohnSaunders Yes of course looked at the documentation.  Nothing interesting there.

Comment: See [`HtmlWindow.Error` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlwindow.error.aspx)